# Let users generate multiple unique embeddable code snippets, embed each so their end users can see my view and make a post request - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my logged in users to click a button and retrieve embeddable code unique to a specific Event that they've already created. The user copy pastes this embeddable code into their own website hosted elsewhere, which will then show their end users my net_promoter_score/new.erb page. The new.erb is a survey their users can fill out and POSTS to the database, and has the correct associated event_id.

I want the new.erb to show up on their site such as this screenshot (see bottom of [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5bj3tle14zbgs1/Screenshot%202020-06-15%2015.40.52.png?dl=0))

New.erb works as is, just want it to be embeddable.

I'm flexible in the approach, whether it's an iFrame or modal, or whatever. I just need it to work as per the screenshot above, and be simple enough to implement that I can understand it (I'm new to coding, so please respond in detail). And needs to be cross compatible in different browsers and websites as I don't know who will be using the embed code.

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_11_203001) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_events_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "net_promoter_scores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "ip"
    t.integer "score"
    t.text "embed_code"
    t.bigint "event_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_net_promoter_scores_on_event_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "full_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "company"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "events", "users"
  add_foreign_key "net_promoter_scores", "events"
end
```

NetPromoterScores Controller

```
class NetPromoterScoresController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
        @net_promoter_score = NetPromoterScore.new
    end

    def create
        @event  = Event.find params[:event_id]
        @net_promoter_score = NetPromoterScore.new nps_params
        @net_promoter_score.event = @event
        if @net_promoter_score.save
            redirect_to  root_path, notice: "saved score"
        else
            #byebug
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "didnt save score"
        end
    end

    private
    def nps_params
        params.require(:net_promoter_score).permit(:ip, :event_id, :score)
    end
end
```

New.erb -- this is the page I want to make embeddable

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>How likely are you to recommend us to a friend or colleague?</h2>

  <div class="select">
    <%= form_for [@event, @net_promoter_score] do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :ip, value: request.remote_ip %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 0, :checked => false, id: "0" %>
      <%= f.label '0', for: "0" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 1, :checked => false, id: "1" %>
      <%= f.label '1', for: "1" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 2, :checked => false, id: "2" %>
      <%= f.label '2', for: "2" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 3, :checked => false, id: "3" %>
      <%= f.label '3', for: "3" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 4, :checked => false, id: "4" %>
      <%= f.label '4', for: "4" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 5, :checked => false, id: "5" %>
      <%= f.label '5', for: "5" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 6, :checked => false, id: "6" %>
      <%= f.label '6', for: "6" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 7, :checked => false, id: "7" %>
      <%= f.label '7', for: "7" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 8, :checked => false, id: "8" %>
      <%= f.label '8', for: "8" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 9, :checked => false, id: "9" %>
      <%= f.label '9', for: "9" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, 10, :checked => false, id: "10" %>
      <%= f.label '10', for: "10" %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide them with an `<iframe>` and the request made after a person clicks on the rating would have to send a request to your app with some form of identification for the user who added it to their app.

Maybe you can provide every user with an external ID so when the request is made you can check what user is sending it.

The reason you want to use an `<iframe>` is so that there is no issue with styling when its embedded onto the site. That screenshot you show looks like they just pin it to the bottom of the body.